# Difference between ${build.version} and ${project.version}

Tags: maven

I find inconsistency in their behavior.

Use case: There is no parent pom. Its a single module project.

When i use build.version in rpm-maven-plugin :

a. it reflects correctly for

```
<configuration>
 <version>${build.version}<version>
</configuration>
```

but when i use it in (this is the profile rpm  build..)

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <properties>
            <comp.version>${build.version}</comp.version>
        </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

At this place, the build.version could not retrieve the version. (I mean the value of comp.version becomes ${build.version} literally)

To avoid that i used ${project.version} , it could fetch version at both places.

But when the project version is an SNAPSHOT version (1.0.0-SNAPSHOT). 
the RPM version in spec file becomes 1.0.0 rather than 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Please show your full pom files...

Comment: Actually this question itself is invalid. There is no such maven property ${build.version}. It was due to imitation from other maven project (where they have defined this property 'build.version' explicitly). But one thing i found , you can't have '-' in RPM version as stated at http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html

Comment: If you configure the rpm-maven-plugin which means no special version definition this will be handled by the rpm-maven-plugin itself without manual handling of this....

Comment: @khmarbaise yes the plugin names the version on its own then , for example if you specify it 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT , it will keep only 1.0.0 in SPEC file generated by it